# Render Array in Vuejs

Tags: arrays, vue.js, object, vuex

I tried to render a list of items by Vuejs, the code below is a simplified version of it. Basically, I need it to display data, the state and data appears in VueDevTool but not on the page.

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <h1>{{this.sendersList.length}}</h1> <!-- 0 -->
        <h1>{{senders.length}}</h1> <!-- 0 -->
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
      export default{
        data () {
          return {
            sendersList: []
          }
        },
        created () {
          this.$store.dispatch('getAllSenders', {
              app_id: this.$route.params.chat_id
            }).then(response => {
              this.sendersList = response
          })
    
        },
        computed: {
           senders(){
             return this.$store.getters.getAllSenders
           }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

[image: Data inside VueDevTool]

Store code returns data as normal, VueDevtool can see it but I cant find away to render it on the front-end

```
getAllMessages(context, data){
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post('messages/getAllMessages', {
          sender_id: data.sender_id
        }).then(response => {
          let payload = []
          for (let index = 0; index < response.data.length; index++) {
            payload.push({
              message_id: response.data[index].message_id,
              message_content: response.data[index].message_content,
              message_type: response.data[index].message_type,
              message_sentiment: response.data[index].message_sentiment,
              sender_id: response.data[index].sender_id,
              user_id: response.data[index].user_id,
              from_sender: response.data[index].from_sender,
              created_date: response.data[index].created_date,
            })
          }
          context.commit('getAllMessages', payload)
          resolve(payload)
        }).catch(error => {
          reject(error)
        })
      })
    },
```

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I edited above, I check on VueDevtool, the data is there, it just not render.

Comment: the best practice is to define a state in your store and commit a mutation inside the axios callback in the action then read that state using a computed property

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes, I tried it, get data directly from store by computed, the same thing happend

Comment: How did you do that using computed property

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I edited the code as above, I can see the state change inside the Devtool, but on the front-end, thing is still unchanged

Comment: @VMCuongOnStackOverflow You're dispatching `getAllSenders`, but the action is named `getAllMessages`. I would double check the names used in your store (for actions/mutations/state/getters).

Answer (score 0):

Try change this

```
<h1>{{this.sendersList.length}}</h1>
```

To this

```
<h1>{{sendersList.length}}</h1>
```